# How can I generate combinations of objects?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a page which allows a user to create option groups, and for each option group create a series of options.

E.g.
Colour
* Green
* Blue
* Red

Size
* Small
* Medium
* Large

Where colour and size are the option groups.

The user can create any number of groups and options.

What I'm struggling to find is a way of creating a list of all the possible variations based on the number of options available.

Ideally what I want is an object with a property called "options" which is an array containing the options that this variation is composed of e.g.

```
[  
  { options : [ { name: "Green" } , { "name" : "Small" } ] },  
  { options : [ { name: "Green" } , { "name" : "Medium" } ] },  
  { options : [ { name: "Green" } , { "name" : "Large" } ] },  
  { options : [ { name: "Blue" } , { "name" : "Small" } ] },  
  { options : [ { name: "Blue" } , { "name" : "Medium" } ] },  
  { options : [ { name: "Blue" } , { "name" : "Large" } ] },  
  { options : [ { name: "Red" } , { "name" : "Small" } ] },  
  { options : [ { name: "Red" } , { "name" : "Medium" } ] },  
  { options : [ { name: "Red" } , { "name" : "Large" } ] },  

]
```

I can imagine that some level of recursion is required but I'm really struggling to write the correct JavaScript code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance

EDIT: Looks like I didn't explain myself correctly, apologies for that.  I can see that some of the solutions provided loop through the colours first and then the sizes, however, as mentioned above the user can create any number of groups whereas those solutions are only limited to 2 groups e.g there might be more option groups like "shoe size", "storage capacity", "screen size" etc

The problem I'm trying to solve is to create stock variations on an e-commerce site, where each product can have different options available.

The final structure will contain more data that I've given in the example above, so more like:

```
[  
  { sku: "PRODUCT1-GRSM", options : [ { name: "Green" } , { "name" : "Small" } ] },  
  { sku: "PRODUCT1-GRMD", options : [ { name: "Green" } , { "name" : "Medium" } ] },  
  { sku: "PRODUCT1-GRLG", options : [ { name: "Green" } , { "name" : "Large" } ] },  
  { sku: "PRODUCT1-BLSM", options : [ { name: "Blue" } , { "name" : "Small" } ] },  
  { sku: "PRODUCT1-BLMD", options : [ { name: "Blue" } , { "name" : "Medium" } ] },  
  { sku: "PRODUCT1-BLLG", options : [ { name: "Blue" } , { "name" : "Large" } ] },  
  { sku: "PRODUCT1-RESM", options : [ { name: "Red" } , { "name" : "Small" } ] },  
  { sku: "PRODUCT1-REMD", options : [ { name: "Red" } , { "name" : "Medium" } ] },  
  { sku: "PRODUCT1-RELG", options : [ { name: "Red" } , { "name" : "Large" } ] },  

]
```

That data will be bound to a table which contains input fields for each generated variation, but it's generating those variations which is the problem.  Thanks

Comment: Your structure doesn't make sense, you can only select eiher `Color` or `Size`. Or do you mean each ["option group"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) being a [`select` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)?

Comment: @Teemu the idea is for the user to use a multiselect for each option group to determine which options are available e.g. this product is available in Green, Red and Blue in Size small, medium and large.  So yes, each "option group" is a multiselect element consisting of "options"

Comment: OK, "option group" just missled me to think about `<optgroup>` elements : ).

Answer (score 1):

This is very old but in case you want to support any number of attributes:

```
function add_variations_to_array(base, variations){
    let ret = [];
    for(let e of base) 
    for(let variation of variations){
        ret.push(e+" - "+variation);
    }
    return ret;
}

//Size, color, material
let attributes = [["S","M","L","XL"],["Red","Green","Blue"],["Wool","Cotton","Steel"]];

//generate variations
let variations = attributes[0];
if(attributes.length > 1){
    for(let i in attributes)
    if(i>0)
        variations = add_variations_to_array(variations, attributes[i]);
}
console.log(variations);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pswkzLga/

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are asking:

```
var color = ["red","blue"];
var size = ["Small","Medium","Large"];

var options = [];

for(var i=0;i<color.length;i++)
{
for(var j = 0;j<size.length;j++)
{
    var item = [];
    item.push({name:color[i]},{name:size[j]});
    options.push({options:item});
}
}
console.log(options);//options will contain your desired result
```

You can dynamically add color, size in `color` and `size` array respectively and you will get the desired output.

Comment: Sorry but as you can see in the edit, there can be more attributes than just colour and size in which case a fixed number of iterations wouldn't work I'm afraid